# Whatsapp cloud api working fine on local but not work on server

Tags: laravel, facebook, facebook-graph-api, whatsapp

I am using laravel framework

My Method:

```
public static function sendWithWhatsapp($to, $code)
{
    $phoneId = '114965591551646';
    $payload = [
        'messaging_product' => 'whatsapp',
        'to' => $to,
        "type" => "template",
        "template" => [
            "name" => "sms_verification",
            "language" => [
                "code" => "en"
            ],
            "components" => [[
                "type" => "body",
                "parameters" => [[
                    "type" => "text",
                    "text" => $code
                ]]
            ]]
        ]
    ];

    return Http::withToken(config('app.whatsapp_bearer'))
        ->post('https://graph.facebook.com/v16.0/' . $phoneId . '/messages', $payload)
        ->throw()->json();
}
```

I think problem is not in my code because it working in local.

What do I need to do for it to work on the server?

The error message returned on the server is as follows:

```
HTTP request returned status code 400:\n{\"error\":{\"message\":\"Unsupported post request. Object with ID '114965591551646' does not exist, cannot be loaded due to  (truncated...)\n
```

Comment: but it say an object with an id does not exist. shouldn't that be your concern? rather than it working on local and not production

Comment: There is no such error in local. The number in this id is available in my whatsapp cloud api account. If i don't get this error locally, why get it on the server?

Comment: Might be the `app.whatsapp_bearer` is not getting or is incorrect, have you setup a properly config environment? try to hard code the token and try is it working or not..

Answer (score 0):

Instead of using withToken()

```
return Http:::withHeaders([
    'Authorization' => 'Bearer ' . config('app.whatsapp_bearer'),
    'Accept'        => 'application/json',
])
->post('https://graph.facebook.com/v16.0/' . $phoneId . '/messages', $payload)
        ->throw()->json();
```

Try this

the error is occurring cause you are suppose to pass token in header and you are not doing that